# Joining dba_users & v$database

Tags: oracle, join

I need to generate a report that displays the account status of all schemas, which I've got.

```
SELECT   
''''|| USERNAME ||''''     USERNAME,
''''|| ACCOUNT_STATUS||'''' ACCOUNT_STATUS,
''''|| LOCK_DATE ||'''' LOCK_DATE,
''''|| PROFILE ||''''     PROFILE
FROM DBA_USERS
WHERE PROFILE='DEFAULT'
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

However the requirement also states that they want the database name on every row in the report, so...

```
SELECT 
''''|| NAME ||'''' 
FROM V$DATABASE
```

My SQL is pretty poor so I tried some sort of mismashed join, but realised that won't work... any ideas?

Comment: You can simply join the v$database view: add `,v$database.name` to your select list and `,v$database` to your from-clause. You don't have to add anything to your where-clause. Or you use "modern" syntax, and add `CROSS JOIN $database` in the from-clause instead. Or you use an  `INNER JOIN v$database ON (PROFILE='DEFAULT') ` and remove the where-condition.

Comment: `select username,name from dba_users, v$database where profile='DEFAULT'`or 
`select username,name from dba_users cross join v$database where profile='DEFAULT'` or 
`select username,name from dba_users join v$database on  profile='DEFAULT'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   
''''|| USERNAME ||''''     USERNAME,
''''|| ACCOUNT_STATUS||'''' ACCOUNT_STATUS,
''''|| LOCK_DATE ||'''' LOCK_DATE,
''''|| PROFILE ||''''     PROFILE,
(SELECT ''''|| NAME ||'''' FROM V$DATABASE) DB_NAME
FROM DBA_USERS
WHERE PROFILE='DEFAULT'
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

or

```
SELECT   
(SELECT ''''|| NAME ||'''' FROM V$DATABASE) DB_NAME,
''''|| USERNAME ||''''     USERNAME,
''''|| ACCOUNT_STATUS||'''' ACCOUNT_STATUS,
''''|| LOCK_DATE ||'''' LOCK_DATE,
''''|| PROFILE ||''''     PROFILE
FROM DBA_USERS
WHERE PROFILE='DEFAULT'
ORDER BY 2,3;
```